# How to stop asking for input after reaching a specific amount of elements in a list?

Tags: python

So I would to use python for a user to enter numbers in sequence lets say ratings

for example

1
2
99

and save those ratings as elements in a list

but I want to add two restrictions the user can enter only **up to** 30 ratings, by up to I mean that the user can enter only two ratings, three, twenty and so on and so fortu but no more than 30 ratings.

And I want to ratings value to be a two digit integer bigger than 0 and smaller than 100

So I would like to have something like:

"please enter your ratings:"

and if a user enters e.g 199 or ADFADF then I want to have an error message and ask to repeat a valid value

or if the user tries to enter more than 30 ratings I would like the program to print a second error message and stop asking of additional input (and save all previous input to the list).

Comment: What did you try? and where are you having trouble achieving this?

Comment: Create an input loop and count how many the user has entered a value and then stop doing it when they reach the limit — just like you would do it by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the validation section you can use printy, this library comes with a function that does that for you, first, install printy:
`pip install printy`

Then import this function
`from printy import inputy`

Now, you have to create a loop that ends when the user has entered up to 30 valid values, and also, another loop that checks whether the value is a two digits value or not. So, something like this:

```
from printy import inputy

ratings = []

while len(ratings) < 30:
    valid_rating = 100  # let's use an invalid value to launch the loop
    while valid_rating >= 100:
        valid_rating = inputy("Enter a rating", type="int", condition="+")
    ratings.append(valid_rating)
```

link to printy: https://github.com/edraobdu/printy

Answer (score -1):

Use continue and break situation wise to make a workable right program.